# ROUND() in SQL Server when dealing with a decimal in varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know the usage of Round() and it works fine for

```
select round(147.26719,5,1)
```

which returns 147.26719.

Currently I am working on a table imported from a txt file so all the column are `varchar`, when I using `round()` to deal with a decimal in varchar like this

```
select round('147.26719',5,1)
```

very weird it returns 147.26718.

I current make it run correctly as

```
select round(cast('147.26719', decimal(11,6)),5,1)
```

but can anybody explains to me why this happens? I believe it is something when implicitly convert the varchar to decimal, but just don't know why.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the implicit conversion of the string for the `round()` is into a `float`, not a decimal.  Floating point numbers are imprecise and might be off just a wee, wee bit from what you see -- but enough to matter.

Your solution is the correct one -- cast to a decimal.

You can readily see this by using code such as:

```
select round('123.3', 1) as col
into x;

select *
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'x';
```

Comment: Alternatively, `select SQL_Variant_Property( Round( '123.3', 1), 'BaseType' );`.

Comment: Thank you! that explains